# Best way to store real time graph points

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was recently asked the following question in a coding interview:

"Given a continuous stream of graph points (X, Y) of a cartesian graph, design a data structure to store them so that searching for all neighboring points at distance k from the given point at anytime should be done in the most efficient way in terms of time complexity."

My idea is to use an associative list. Every node of the list will have X point as key and its corresponding Y point as the value. Please suggest any better data structure.

Thanks

Comment: quad tree...............

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_tree

See also K-DTree, Quad Tree, etc.

For example, finding the k nearest neighbors in a k-d tree will take O(k log n), or O(log n) for constant k, time.

Storing the points in an X -> Y mapping will not help you, as points far away from each other along the X dimension can still be nearest neighbors if their Y coordinates are very close.